# Solve for an Undetermined Coefficent by using annihilator method.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The problem is [image]

I know that we need to find [image] and [image]

There are three roots and at least two of them are complex.

[image]

Edit: Sorry I forgot the D = 1
The [image] is supposed to  be [image]. The + right next to the sinx is just a typo.

Now for the [image] . Since there is a [image] on the right hand side of the equation, we need to use [image]. Do I expand the equation to take three derivatives? I know that there's going to be a lot of product rule executions. Is there an easier way to do this problem? I've heard about the annihilator method, but I don't know how to use it. I could do variation of parameters, but it produces too many overwhelming variables.

This is what I got so far for the first derivative of Yp. I figure if I put the a and b aside for a bit and take the product rule for the terms, it may be easier.

This is a screenshot of my first derivative and my second derivative of Yp
[image]

Comment: This link might help you format your question. It will be easier to read and you won't have to upload pictures. I highly recommend it: http://mathoverflow.net/editing-help

Comment: Thanks. I'm new to this site, so I don't know how to do LaTex on here

Comment: Just put the LaTeX code between dollar signs: `$\LaTeX$` gives $\LaTeX$.

Comment: @usukidoll: I added the intermediate derivatives to the solution. Please work through those.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll do so and combine like terms

Comment: @usukidoll: Did you get the result? Regards

Comment: I'm drying up and taking a break at the moment, but I'll return to this after I eat dinner. I'm sure I'll be able to finally get the result

Comment: Thank you for your help @Amzoti! I was able to get $-2e^x(acosx+bsinx)$ and got A=1/2 and B=0

Comment: Excellent, of course you meant $a = -1/2$.

Comment: Yes I got a = -1/2. sorry I stayed up until 3 am trying to finish my homework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent system is:

$$y''' - 3 y'' + 4 y' -2y = e^x \cos x$$

The homogeneous solution gives us $m^3 - 3m^2 + 4 m -2 = 0 \rightarrow m= 1, 1 \pm i$, so:

$$y_h(x) = e^x(c_1 + c_2 \cos x + c_3 \sin x)$$

Now, we notice that we have an $e^x \cos x$ term in the particular solution, we multiply by an $x$ term, so we choose:

$$y_p(x) = x~e^x(a \cos x + b \sin x)$$

We now form $y''' - 3 y'' + 4 y' -2y = e^x \cos x$ and solve for the constants.

Yes, you need to form the first, second and third derivative, it is a bit of algebra, but there are also many cancellations.

**Update**

- $y'_p = e^x x (b \cos x - a \sin x) + e^x (a \cos x + b \sin x) + 
   e^x x (a \cos x + b \sin x)$
- $y''_p = 2 e^x (b \cos x - a \sin x) + 2 e^x x (b \cos x - a \sin x) + 
   e^x x (-a \cos x - b \sin x) + 2 e^x (a \cos x + b \sin x) + 
   e^x x (a \cos x + b \sin x)$
- $y'''_p = 6 e^x (b \cos x - a \sin x) + 3 e^x x (b \cos x - a \sin x) + 
   e^x x (-b \cos x + a \sin x) + 3 e^x (-a \cos x - b \sin x) + 
   3 e^x x (-a \cos x - b \sin x) + 3 e^x (a \cos x + b \sin x) + 
   e^x x (a \cos x + b \sin x)$
- Now, you have to form $y_p''' - 3 y_p'' + 4 y_p' -2y_p$

**Spoiler**

> $$y(x) =  e^x (c_1 + c_2 \cos x + c_3 \sin x -\dfrac{1}{2} x~ \cos x)$$

**Notes:**

- $(1)$ Variation of parameters may actually be easier to use.
- $(2)$ You can see some examples of the [*Annihilator Method*](http://dankalman.net/AUhome/classes/classesF12/odes/assignments/annihilatormethod.pdf)
- $(3)$ If you want an alternate method to undertermined coeeficients or the Ann Method, see example $2$ of [*AN ALTERNATIVE METHOD FOR THE UNDETERMINED COEFFICIENTS AND THE ANNIHILATOR METHODS*](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1110.4425v3.pdf)

Comment: I was going to do it with variation of parameters, but I'm wondering if it creates a hassle because you have to do Cramer's Rule and find the Wronskian which is easy to do. I mean when the terms in the Wronskian are lengthy...and you have to do some calculation wouldn't it create more hassles since you have to distribute?

Comment: Sometimes problems are complicated regardless if we have several approaches. The approach I did first is easiest, but has some messy algebra. yes, with VoP, you will have several $3x3$ Wronskians to solve and that is messy too with the particular expressions. Pick your poison. Regards

Comment: Alright so when I find the first, second, and third derivatives do I set the A and B aside and do product rule? Or do I set the e^x aside?

Comment: Take the $y_p$, the three derivatives and then equate to the RHS to the LHS. Pick the constants so both sides are equal. There will be lots of cancellations and we end up with $a = \frac{1}{2}, b = 0$. Is this clear? If you have issues, give a yell.

Comment: I think it would be easier to set the a and b aside for the Yh and just take the product rules of the first, second, and third derivative.

Comment: Leave the homogeneous solution alone because that will give you $0 = 0$ when you substitute it in. You only need to do this for the particular $y_p$. Clear?

Comment: Oh I meant the Yp sorry about that... what I meant was to put the a and b aside to take the derivatives of Yp up to the third derivative

Comment: I am not sure I follow since we are trying to determine $a$ and $b$, but if you have an alternate approach, give it a go!

Comment: I'll post a screenshot of the first derivative of Yp

Comment: Yes, that is correct for the 1st derivative. Two more to go.

Comment: woo! Awesome alright usuki! You can do this thing :D

Comment: Ok I revised the image with the first and second derivative. Does everything look ok?
And then I take the third derivative of this massive equation. Do I set all of the constants aside like since there are a lot of 2's and there are letters,A and B, I should put them on the side for the bit and take the derivative of the variables.

Comment: For the LHS, after all simplifications and cancellations, for $y''' - 3 y'' + 4 y' -2y$ you should get: $-2 e^x (a \cos x + b \sin x)$.

Comment: Quick question...do I put the original $Yp$ in the y for the equation $y'''$-$3y''$+$4y'$-$2y$

Comment: Yes, you will form $y_p'''−3y_p''+4y_p'−2y_p$ and then equate it to the RHS. You will end up with $−2e^x(a \cos x+ b \sin x) = e^x \ cos x$ and then solve for $a$ and $b$.

Comment: for some reason...I got $8Asinxe^x$+$4Ae^xcosx$-$2Be^xsinx$=$e^xcosx$

Comment: Some algebra mistakes.

Comment: I got this as the third derivative... 

$Y'''(p)$=$-2Bxe^xsinx$+$xcosxe^x$+$6Be^xcosx$-$2Axe^xcosx$-$2Axsinxe^x$+$2Asinxe^x$

so it could either be that one of the derivatives is wrong or all of the $Yp$ derivatives are right and something slipped after distribution

Comment: Here is the third derivative: $$\begin{multline}6 e^x (b \cos x - a \sin x) + 3 e^x x (b \cos x - a \sin x) + 
 e^x x (-b \cos x + a \sin x) + \\ 3 e^x (-a \cos x - b \sin x) + 3 e^x x (-a \cos x - b \sin x) + \\ 3 e^x (a \cos x + b \sin x) + 
 e^x x (a \cos x + b \sin x).\end{multline}$$ Recall that you have the derivatives, but also have the constants in the ODE to multiply them by.

Comment: Wait a minute... how is there a $6e^x$ on the $(bcosx-asinx)$

Is the second derivative correct? Because if it's not, then there will be errors for the third.

Comment: Maybe you should look at the second derivative, which ends up with constant $2$'s and then these keep adding up. Clear?

Comment: I do have a lot of 2's on the second derivative...did I took the product rule wrong on some variables?

Comment: can I ask you something? I know we needed to multiply the $Y_p$ with x since there was a $e^{x}cosx$ already on the right side of the equation. Why didn't we multiply the whole $Y_p$ with $x^2$? Just a question that popped up.  @Amzoti

Comment: We multiply by one greater exponent than we have in the RHS. SO, if we had $x e^x \cos x$, we would try something like (ax^2 + bx + c)(x e^x \cos x$).